# Regular expression to remove everything but words. java

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

This code doesn't seem doing the right job. It removes the spaces between the words!

```
input = scan.nextLine().replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");
```

I want to remove all extra spaces and all numbers or abbreviations from a string, except words and this character: `'`.

For Example:

input`:     34 4fF$#@D   one   233 r   #   o'clock 329riewio23`

returns: `one o'clock`

Comment: What have you already tried? What seems to be a problem?

Comment: @PM77-1 I forgot to add the code. its there now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static String filter(String input) {
    return input.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9' ]", "").replaceAll(" +", " ");
}
```

The first replace replaces all characters except alphabetic characters, the single-quote, and spaces. The second replace replaces all instances of one or more spaces, with a single space.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution doesn't work because you don't replace numbers and you also replace the `'` character.

Check out this solution:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^| ][A-Za-z']{2,} ");
String input = scan.nextLine();
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
while (matcher.find()) {
    result.append(matcher.group());
}
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

It looks for the beginning of the string or a space (`[^| ]`) and then takes all the following characters (`[A-Za-z']`). However, it only takes the word if there are 2 or more charactes (`{2,}`) and there has to be a trailing space.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to just extract that time information use this regex group match:

```
input = scan.nextLine();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]{3,})\\s.*?(o'clock)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
if (m.find()) {
    input = m.group(1) + " " + m.group(2);
}
```

The regex is quite naive though, and will only work if the input is always of a similar format.